# Reference a result tab

Tags: powerbi, kql

I need your assistance with my KQL function that I need to query via Power BI in DirectQuery mode.

My KQL function consists of multiple queries that I execute via batches. At one point however, I used the fork function as I am referring to a single source and expect to have multiple subqueries with different calculations. Those three tables return the desired output in an equal schema, but unfortunately Power BI is unable to import the output and it returns an internal server error:

```
DataSoure.Error: Web.Contents failed to get contents from '[Source]' (520):InternalServiceError
Details:
   DateSourceKind=AzureDataExplorer
   DataSourcePath=[Source]
   Url = [URL]
```

The idea I had was to union the three result tables back to one, but this is where I am struggling. The documentation on Microsofts website on the fork operator [1] refers to the materialize function to join or union each fork leg later, but I was unable to code it correctly. My main issue is that I do not know how to reference each result tab.

Here is an example of the code piece that cause the issue:

```
let forkedResults = MyTable
| fork (
    Output1 = (where attribute = 'abc'),
    Output2 = (where attribute = 'def')
  );
Output1
|union Output2
```

This code returns the error that neither Output1 nor Output2 are known references to any columns/tables/functions nor variables.

The following code returns the desired result, but is lackluster in performance:

```
let Output1 = MyTable
|where attribute = 'abc';

let Output2 = MyTable
|where attribute = 'def'

Output1
|union Output2
```

The question I have: Can I either work around the Power BI connector to query my initial function, or is there a way to materialize the fork legs to address them in a later union statement?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/forkoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer

Answer (score 0):

regarding the last part of your question, you can replace this:

```
let Output1 = MyTable
| where attribute == 'abc'
;
let Output2 = MyTable
| where attribute == 'def'
;
Output1
| union Output2
```

with this:

```
MyTable
| where attribute in('abc','def')
```

regarding the first part - there's the [`materialize()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/materializefunction) you can use, but you should only use it for relatively smaller intermediate results that may be reused, and not for materializing very large data sets.

you can also look into using [stored query results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The query I mentioned in my statement was oversimplified. I am doing additional calculations in each subaltern, which use different aggregations. Therefore I cannot simply use an in statement to make the query easier